# MsBuild: Do not compile referenced project

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, compilation, nant

I have the following project structure:

```
SLN
    libA
    libB (references libA)
    exeWPF (references libA and libB)
```

I use NAnt to compile libA and libB, with csc, but I cannot use csc with the WPF project, XAML targets cannot be compiled with NAnt, so I use a MSBuild task inside the NAnt project.

The problem is that when I launch a complete build, libA and libB are already by NAnt, and then when the MSBuild task is launched, the `libA` and `libB` libraries are compiled **again**, because the `exeWPF` csproj file references the libA and the libB projects.

An alternative could be instead referencing `libA` and `libB` as projects, I could reference them as dlls in the `exeWPF` csproj file. The problem is that in this case I loose the code and, navigate to reference.

The solution for me would be to be able to specify from the MSBuild task the references to the MsBuild project.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can build your `exeWPF` project like this

```
msbuild exeWPF.csproj /p:BuildProjectReferences=false
```

Property BuildProjectReferences will prevent MSBuild from building references, it will be forced to use pre-built assemblies to extract metadata for references, and it will fail if referenced assemblies don't exist.